# Associate PHP index with another array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, foreach

I have 3 explode statements:

```
$emails = explode(',', $row['email']);
$firstnames = explode(',', $row['first_name']);
$lastnames = explode(',', $row['last_name']);
```

each `explode` produces three (3) arrays:

```
//emails
Array
(
    [0] => test123@example.com
    [1] => lol123@example.com
    [2] => haha@example.com
    [3] => blahblah@example.com
)

//first name
Array
(
    [0] => Bill
    [1] => Jake
    [2] => John
    [3] => Bob
)

//last name
Array
(
    [0] => Jones
    [1] => Smith
    [2] => Johnson
    [3] => Bakers
)
```

I can get the one array easily like this: for example:

```
foreach ($emails as $email) {
    echo $email;
}
```

That will echo out the emails. But I want to add `$firstname` and `$lastname` into it. for example, I want to echo:

```
test123@example.com Bill Jones
```

how can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

foreach can assign a key and value if you use the appropriate syntax:

```
foreach ($emails as $key => $email) {
    echo $email;
    echo $firstnames[$key];
    echo $lastnames[$key];
}
```

Next time, consult the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php as this is shown at the very top.

As Pyromonk pointed out, for is useful in situations where you have indexed arrays:

```
for ($i = 0, $n = count($emails); $i < $n; $i++) {
    echo $emails[$i];
    echo $firstnames[$i];
    echo $lastnames[$i];
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, a `for` loop could be used instead of `foreach`, as it would make more sense in this context.